# Python requests: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

My situation

1. I have tried this request on postman and it work perfectly.
2. I use python requests
3. I want to get admin token from code below

```
import requests
import json

url = '<URL host>/rest/V1/integration/admin/token'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
body = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "p@ssword_contain_special_character"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers).json()
print(response)
print(response['message'])
```

error I recieved

```
Decoding error: 
Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer/Json.php(64): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('username=wsuser...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(141): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Json->deserialize('username=wsuser...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(199): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request->getBodyParams()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(97): Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request->getRequestData()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->___callParent('resolve', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->___callPlugins('resolve', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->resolve()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#17 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert dictonary into json string format.

Try

```
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers).json()
```

Thanks